# Get particular matching values from json array using php code

Tags: php, json, api

This is my response code:

```
'[{"id":"153","title":"xyz","description":"abc"}, 
{"id":"154","title":"xyy","description":"abb"}]'
```

in this code i need to get values from id=154  only and i need only that particular array values only using php code?

if I have variable $a=154;
it will get that particular id  and title and description values only.
if I have variable $a=153;
it will get that particular id and title and description values only.

Comment: Take a look at the [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$jsonStr  = '[
              {"id":"153","title":"xyz","description":"abc"}, 
              {"id":"154","title":"xyy","description":"abb"}
             ]';
$arrJson  = json_decode($jsonStr);
$keyVal   = 154;
foreach($arrJson as $key => $val){
if($val->id == $keyVal){
    echo $val->id;//Id
    echo $val->title;//Title
    echo $val->description;//Descrption
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Javascript` :

```
json[0].id
```

Using `PHP` :

```
$json  = json_decode($your_json_str);
echo $json[0]->id;
```

You can get the value `153`.

```
$a = 153;

foreach($json as $key => $element){
if($element->id == $a){
    echo $element->id,"<br>";
    echo $element->title,"<br>";
    echo $element->description,"<br>";
   }
}
```